# C++ Visual studio jsoncpp: How to drill down json paths

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio, jsoncpp

Trying to figure out the syntax for using jsonCPP in visual studio to drill down into a json file.
Not sure how to go beyond the first layer. An example can be seen in the picture as a use case with: "events.pages.list.parameters" being the main path I want to drill down too. Some of these paths are arrays that contain objects making it more confusing on how to properly drill down.

Basic script example.

```
int main() {
ifstream file("Map001.json");
Json::Reader reader;
Json::Value completeJsonData;
reader.parse(file, completeJsonData);
cout << "Name: " << completeJsonData["?????"] << endl;
```

}
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Any particular reason for using this exact library ? Can't find anything in the docs about walking through an object (http://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/index.html). What about Boost JSON or nlohmann/JSON ? Both provide iterators for doing that.